# AEM: Handle submit event of a CQ Dialog after validation

Tags: aem

I'm trying to run some js code before a AEM CQ Dialog submit event. I achieved it handling next event:

```
    $(document).on("click", ".cq-dialog-submit", function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        //More code
        $(this).closest("form.foundation-form").submit();
    });
```

This works, but is skipping the AEM form validation and lets required fields to go empty.

Any idea to add an action just after the fields are valid, but to control when the submit must go?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use pre submit hook

```js
$(window).adaptTo("foundation-registry").register("foundation.form.submit", {
    selector: "*",
    handler: function () {
       // custom code
    }
});
```

It will be executed before every TouchUI Dialog submit and after all validations